# How to use more than one visualization type to a chart in superset?

Tags: charts, visualization, dashboard, apache-superset

I need to create a chart that shows 2 types of visualizations (columns and rows). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't use two charts on the same dashboard?